# with pandas read_sql, how do I run procedure with parameters?

Tags: python, pandas, plsql

I have a stored procedure which as been created like this :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MyTestProcedure(p_date IN DATE)
AS
OUTPUT SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
END
```

I would like to execute it doing :

```
pd.read_sql("""EXECUTE MyTestProcedure @p_date=(TO_DATE('2022-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))"""
```

but this does throw an error :

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'EXECUTE MyTestProcedure @p_date=(TO_DATE('2022-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))': ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

what am I missing there ?

Comment: I would try wrapping the sql in a select statement e.g. SELECT MyTestProcedure(TO_DATE('2022-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) FROM DUAL.

Comment: I don't know Python, but a procedure name on its own isn't a complete statement. You might try passing a PL/SQL block e.g. `begin MyTestProcedure(params); end;`